# Glide: the number of load attempts when network error

Tags: android, android-glide

Can I setup count of attempts for downloading image? When network error was occurred, glide automatically reloads an image?

Answer (score 0):

My first question: Why do you want to automatically re-download an image which threw an error? isn't it gonna just throw the error again? In a loop nonetheless.

I would throw the error to the user and let the user decide (for example when the user forgot to turn on Wifi, detect this and let the user turn it on, then let the user click a button to try again).

But what you're asking for can be done, you want the RequestListener class.
From: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling

> Although enabling debug logging is simple, it's only possible if you
>   have access to the device. To integrate Glide with a pre-existing or
>   more sophisticated error logging system, you can use the
>   RequestListener class. onException() will be called when the request
>   fails and will provide the Exception that caused the failure, or null
>   if a decoder was unable to decode anything useful from the data it
>   received. You can pass your listener in to each request using the
>   listener() API.
>
> Be sure to return false from onException() to avoid overriding Glide's
>   default error handling behavior (for example notifying the Target of
>   the error).

Comment: Thank you, but I read this article. It is necessary to collect urls of images that not loads in code and restart their loading. I need in this feature because user can have non stable connection, that can be lost during downloading.